# "selenium webdriverwait class" syntax error is there any problem in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I m planning to automate whatsapp replies with selenium so i used webdriver class and created a object. While compiling it shows syntax error. Though i checked it was correct.

I tried importing all class related to webdriver or i would have missed some.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

target=str(input("Enter the contact name: "))
string = str(input('Enter your message: '))
n = int(input('spam count: '))

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
print("Scan the QR code with your android mobile from whatsapp")
time.sleep(60)

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title, '+ '"' +target + '"'+ ')]'
print(x_arg)
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);*//Error line*
person_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x_arg)))
print(person_title)
person_title.click()
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))

for i in range(n):
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)
```

> File "bot.py", line 19
>       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

Answer (score 3):

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);` is Java syntax, not Python.

Python doesn't use type declaration, doesn't use `new` for objects and doesn't use `;` at line end.

It should be

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
```

//Error line*
Replace this with below line

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a colon (";") at the end of the line. No need for that in Python.